# Update a boolean variable in Ansible upon a condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have started working with Ansible recently and I have a condition where I have to update the value of a a variable upon a condition. I have tried looking it up but I could not find a good way to do it.

```
#I am defining the final_result variable here, which would be updated after executing every single step. Sample step given below. 
- name: Define variable
  set_fact:
      fianl_result: True

- name: First of the N steps to be executed. 
  command: "my shell command here"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: test_result

- name: Updating final_result variable
  set_fact:
      fianl_result: final_result and False
  when: test_result.rc == 0  and test_result.stderr.find("Error':' flag needs an argument") == -1  

- name: Second of the N steps to be executed. 
  command: "my shell command here"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: test_result

- name: Updating final_result variable
  set_fact:
      fianl_result: final_result and False
  when: test_result.rc == 0  and test_result.stderr.find("Error':' flag needs an argument") == -1
```

Basically I am trying to do something like this in python:

```
final_result = True 
if test_result == False: 
    final_result = final_result and False
```

I would like to update the variable final_result after every step, can anyone help me with this please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve with `final_result and False` as I am not clear what you are trying to do. Wrapping it in `"{{ }}"` will cause it to be evaluated via Jinja2 but I am not sure how it differs from just setting the value to `False`.

Comment: @clockworknet : Thanks for the jinja tip, i'll try to use that. I have multiple steps, (say 5 steps) to be executed in succession. The final result would be updated to false if atleast one of them fails. So, after every step, I update the final_result as shown in the python code above, which is basically setting the final_result to false if atleast one step fails.

Comment: I understand your use case, but I think `final_result and False` would always evaluate to False, plus you are only running the `set_fact` task when you know the task has failed. So you set `final_result: True` at the start, and then only revisit in the event that a task fails, at which point all you would need to do is  `final_result: False`.  I may well be missing something tho. :(

Comment: Thanks, this would work. I will be copy pasting your comment as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @clockworknet, the following worked for me.

final_result and False would always evaluate to False, plus you are only running the set_fact task when you know the task has failed. So you set final_result: True at the start, and then only revisit in the event that a task fails, at which point all you would need to do is final_result: False